# React app not working with firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase

My react app works fine locally... But not after deploying to firebase hosting.

Chrome's inspector's network tab shows that https://another-netflix-clone.web.app/ is prepended to each api call... https://another-netflix-clone.web.app/api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=key&with_genres=27

This is a problem.  Not sure why this is happening.

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hosting Setup:

```
=== Hosting Setup

Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that
will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you
have a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.

? What do you want to use as your public directory? build
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
✔  Wrote build/index.html

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

✔  Firebase initialization complete!
chaselwander@W-MD-ML-CHASEL chad_neflix_clone (master)*$ npm run build

> chad_neflix_clone@0.1.0 build /Users/chaselwander/projects/react_netflix_clone/chad_neflix_clone
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.
```

The app:

https://another-netflix-clone.web.app/

Snippet of API calling code:

```
/* example fetchUrl value: https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/trending/all/week?api_key=${APIKEY}&language=en-US */

function Row({ title, fetchUrl, isLargeRow }) {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [trailerUrl, setTrailerUrl] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
      setMovies(request.data.results);
      return request;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchUrl]);
```

I ran the app using the build folder locally... it works just fine.

```
serve -s build
```

**Updated description of the issue:**

I really just need help figuring out why this firebase generated app url:

```
https://another-netflix-clone.web.app/
```

Is prepended to each api call:

```
Request URL: https://another-netflix-clone.web.app/api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/tv?api_key=2ce4f6136730519d5877eb7a94b4e21e&with_networks=213
```

Locally when I run:

```
serve -s build
```

The api call is correct and data is returned:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/tv?api_key=2ce4f6136730519d5877eb7a94b4e21e&with_networks=213
```

Comment: Show the code for your API call. This has nothing to do with firebase.

Comment: Your app doesn't work, check console logs, there are many errors, deployment works fine but your code is broken. Try npm run build locally, run index.html from the build folder and see how it behaves.

Comment: Thanks All!
It certainly could be my code... however running the build folder locally works without error.  I updated my post with more info.

Comment: Can you please `console.log(fetchUrl)` and share a screenshot of output? I'd like to see the url in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version the current bug is here:

```js
 console.log(movies);
  // install Quokka to print results to editor
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <div className="row__posters">
        {movies.map((movie) => (
          <img
            key={movie.id}
            onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
            className={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && "row__posterLarge"}`}
            src={`${base_url}${
              isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path
            }`}
            alt={movie.name}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      {trailerUrl && <YouTube videoId={trailerUrl} opts={opts} />}
    </div>
  );
```

try to rewrite it to this:

```js
 console.log(movies);
  // install Quokka to print results to editor
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <div className="row__posters">
        {movies && movies.map((movie) => (
          <img
            key={movie.id}
            onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
            className={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && "row__posterLarge"}`}
            src={`${base_url}${
              isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path
            }`}
            alt={movie.name}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      {trailerUrl && <YouTube videoId={trailerUrl} opts={opts} />}
    </div>
  );
```

And yes this has nothing to do with Firebase hosting.

Also update your `axios.js` file to:

```js
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  },
});

export default instance;
```

Comment: Thank you Tarik!

The app loads now... but no data is returned from the api calls...
the endpoint urls are still being prepended with the app url:
`https://chad-netflix-clone-a9f63.web.app`
This can be seen in the network tab.  I'm very confused by this.

Comment: @Hase134 I don't think that we can debug your whole code until it works. Each question on stackoverflow should be about a ingle error/topic. We need to keep it clean and struktured. Othervise no one could find any answer here.

Comment: Tarik I agree... and I appreciate the help you have provided.  But the issue I'm asking about still remains... I updated the description to be more clear about what is happening.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some minimal project or code we can run on our side? Can you show screenshots how the side looks like when working as you said `serve -build`. For me it looks like a possible CORS issue but I don't know why no errors are shown for that.

Comment: Sure thing Tarik... here is the code:
[https://github.com/CH34MKE10/react_netflix_clone](https://github.com/CH34MKE10/react_netflix_clone)

The code live on firebase hosting:
[https://another-netflix-clone.web.app/](https://another-netflix-clone.web.app/)

The preview & the response tabs under the network tab say:
**You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.**
However I can run javascript in chrome's console so idk?

Comment: Check the updated answer. I found the bug :)

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you Tarik!  I'm puzzled why this didn't break when running locally.  Anyway thanks again!

Comment: Without the `https://` axios took (when deployed) your domain as basis so you always ended up on your won website calling it and not the API. I noticed it when I logged the `response.data`. It was showing HTML from your site.

Comment: It woul be great if you could mark the answer as accepted so other know that this question is resoled.